# BMX head tube logo identify?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx, badge

[image: looks like the Airwalks symbol]

Please help me figure out what brand of BMX bike this is?

It looks like the A Logo for the airwalks shoe brand.

Comment: Have you tried searching for Airwalk BMX logo?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it does seem to be the same logo.

From "How to build an Airwalk Bike"

at 4 min 7 seconds:

[image]

And at 4 min 34 seconds:

[image]